# How to suggest changes to Android Gboard built-in keyboard layouts?

Tags: gboard

The built-in Nepali keyboard layout in Android Gboard is missing several characters and is generally awkward to use.

Is there a way to suggest changes to it?

Answer (score 2):

GBoard is a closed source app by Google, so modifying it is not that simple.

In my opinion the best chance is to create a new issue in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).